# Is the following usage of the verb "be" correct? Why do people keep telling me it's wrong?

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement

> There **is** a plethora of other examples of blatant mistreatment which
> I'll gladly share with anyone who cares enough to listen.

Should I use the plural instead?

> There **are** a plethora of other examples of blatant mistreatment which
> I'll gladly share with anyone who cares enough to listen.

Comment: Search for “there is” and “there are” to find relevant answers. Use the search bar on this page.

Answer (score 0):

According to Collins dictionary "plethora" is a singular noun, so "is" would seem to be correct.

See: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/plethora

Comment: Yes, but the same could be said of *lot* and *number*, and yet we say 'there are a lot of . . .' and 'there are a number of . . .'. The question is whether *plethora* is analogous to *lot* and *number*.